# How to monkey patch inner ruby class?

Tags: ruby

There is a bug with old versions of Net::FTP :

```
f = Net::FTP.new
f.close

Net::FTPConnectionError: not connected
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/ftp.rb:1032:in `method_missing'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/ftp.rb:908:in `close'
        from (irb):17
        from /usr/local/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

This bug has been fixed in Ruby 2+ by adding a null-method #close to NullSocket but is still in 1.9.3

I want to patch the inner class NullSocket like this :

```
if defined?(Net::FTP::NullSocket) and !Net::FTP::NullSocket.instance_methods.include?(:close)
  class Net::FTP::NullSocket
     def close
      # Do nothing 'cause it's a null-method in a null-object
    end
  end
end
```

But it don't works. I get the exact same error as if method_missing was called instead of my new close method.

What strange is that if I get a reference to the inner private @sock variable, I can call close on it without raising the exception.

```
irb(main):010:0* f = Net::FTP.new
=> #<Net::FTP:0x00000000f5d048 @mon_owner=nil, @mon_count=0, @mon_mutex=#<Mutex:0x00000000f5cff8>, @binary=true, @passive=false, @debug_mode=false, @resume=false, @sock=#<Net::FTP::NullSocket:0x00000000f5cfd0>, @logged_in=false>
irb(main):011:0> z = f.instance_variable_get('@sock')
=> #<Net::FTP::NullSocket:0x00000000f5cfd0>
irb(main):012:0> z.methods
=> [:method_missing, :close, :nil?, :===, :=~, :!~, :eql?, :hash, :<=>, :class, :singleton_class, :clone, :dup, :initialize_dup, :initialize_clone, :taint, :tainted?, :untaint, :untrust, :untrusted?, :trust, :freeze, :frozen?, :to_s, :inspect, :methods, :singleton_methods, :protected_methods, :private_methods, :public_methods, :instance_variables, :instance_variable_get, :instance_variable_set, :instance_variable_defined?, :instance_of?, :kind_of?, :is_a?, :tap, :send, :public_send, :respond_to?, :respond_to_missing?, :extend, :display, :method, :public_method, :define_singleton_method, :object_id, :to_enum, :enum_for, :==, :equal?, :!, :!=, :instance_eval, :instance_exec, :__send__, :__id__]
irb(main):013:0> z.close
```

Is there a way to patch such an inner class ?

**Update**

I finally workaround by patching Net::FTP#close

```
class Net::FTP
  def close
    @sock.close if @sock && !@sock.is_a?(NullSocket) && !@sock.closed?
  end
end
```

But the real answer to this question is to patch the right method as explained by David:

```
if defined?(Net::FTP::NullSocket) and !Net::FTP::NullSocket.instance_methods.include?(:'closed?')
  class Net::FTP::NullSocket
    def closed?
      true
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: what's the bug? The exception you're getting (`Net::FTPConnectionError: not connected`) seems sensible.

Comment: The OP seems to be wrong about this being a bug that was fixed.  `Net::FTP.new.close` raises the same exception for me in Ruby 2.2.0.  If you look at https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/lib/net/ftp.rb you can see they still have the same basic structure; they call `@sock.closed?` on the NullSocket, which raises an exception.

Comment: @DavidGrayson you are right again. The have implemented NullSocket#close but not NullSocket#closed?

Comment: is patching the right way to go even in recent ruby versions? 2.2.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The backtrace provided by Ruby shows the exception is raised by line 908 of ftp.rb, which reads:

```
def close
  @sock.close if @sock and not @sock.closed?
end
```

You can see that code [on GitHub](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v1_9_3_551/lib/net/ftp.rb#L907-909) or on your local computer at the path indicated in the stack trace.

The `@sock` object is a NullSocket object, so when `@sock.closed?` is called, it will just raise an exception.  You should monkey patch `closed?` to return `true` and then it probably will be unnecessary to monkey patch `close` because it won't get called.

To answer your question: yes, it is possible to monkeypatch classes included in the Ruby standard library.